# credit card payback wording

Tags: credit-card

I am applying for a new credit card in Germany and am confused by the wording a bit (I just threw it into google translate).

> Convenient transfer service
>
> We arrange the transfer to your checking account. For security
>   reasons, we can only transfer to the account from which the monthly
>   direct debit is collected. After a short time you can dispose of the
>   money. Credit rating provided, maximum your free limit.
>
> Please transfer from my credit card account to my deposited reference
>   account: [x EUR]

Is this amount I give a minimum spending each month? If I don't tick this option I have to accept:

> Please confirm that you are acting on your own account. We ask for
>   your understanding that we can not open accounts on a third party
>   account.

Answer (score 2):

> Convenient transfer service
>
> We arrange the transfer to your checking account. For security
>   reasons, we can only transfer to the account from which the monthly
>   direct debit is collected.

This part appears to be related to getting a cash advance. If some month you want to borrow cash from your credit card. They will only transfer money to the same checking account that is used to pay the bill. They won't allow you to transfer the money to a different account. It cuts down on fraud. Otherwise a person who stole your password could transfer funds to an account the thief  has access to.